# Proving that ℚ is denumerable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that there's a surjection Ψ of ℕ onto ℚ⁺. How do I use this fact to deduce that ℚ is denumerable?

Comment: What is your definition of "denumerable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know that $\Psi$ enumerates $\mathbb{Q}^+$, you can easily construct $\Psi^\prime$ enumerating $\mathbb{Q}$ like so:

$\Psi^\prime(n) = \cases{\Psi(n/2)\textrm{ if $n>0$ and $n$ is even}\\-\Psi((n+1)/2)\textrm{ if $n$ is odd}\\0 \textrm{ if $n=0$ }}$

Comment: But 0 ∉ ℕ, all n must belong to ℕ no? I suppose I could map the first even n to 0 and the rest to ℚ⁺ correct?

Comment: Whether you include $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$ is a matter of convention, but yes, you can easily do that.

Comment: Very well then, thanks a lot!